# javascript event listener for changes in an object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object variable that has several properties.

```
MyVar = {"prop1" : 0, "prop2": 0....};
```

How do I write an event listener that listens for a change in any of the properties.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you seen these? * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063813/listener-for-property-value-changes-in-a-javascript-object
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240592/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-changes-to-an-objects-attributes-in-javascript
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138189/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-callback-when-an-object-creates-or-modifies-a-key-val
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With ES5 you have setters:

```
var MyVar = {
  _prop1: 0,
  get prop1() { return this._prop1; },
  set prop1(value) { this._prop1 = value; /*Listener code can go here*/ }
};
```

Comment: There is also now the [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), too, which is a bit like getters and settings in that the consumer can just use normal assignment (`=`) and property access `object.property` or `object[propertyKey]`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to fire off events when an objects variable changes, you could set up a small Observer pattern for that obj.

```
var MyVar = {
    prop1: "Foo",
    prop2: "Bar",
    events: {},

    setProp1: function(prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.notify('prop1', this.prop1);
    },

    setProp2: function(prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
        this.notify('prop2', this.prop1);
    },

    addEvent: function(name) {
        if (typeof this.events[name] === "undefined") {
            this.events[name] = [];
        }
    },

    register: function(event, subscriber) {
        if (typeof subscriber === "object" && typeof subscriber.notify === 'function') {
            this.addEvent(event);
            this.events[event].push(subscriber);
        }
    },

    notify: function(event, data) {
        var events = this.events[event];
        for (var e in events) {
            events[e].notify(data);
        }
    }
};

var Prop1 = {
    notify: function() {
        alert('prop1 changed');
    }
};

var Prop2 = {
    notify: function() {
        alert('prop2 changed');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    MyVar.register('prop1',Prop1);
    MyVar.register('prop2',Prop2);

    MyVar.setProp1('New Var');
    MyVar.setProp2('New Var');
});
```

Usage instead of setting the object property directly you use a setter method which then fires off a notify event to other objects that are watching it.

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cLvowsLv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you are doing this for debugging proposes, you can add a listener using your `debugging tool at your browser` same way you debug script.

Personally I'm using `Firebug` in Firefox, once opened, go to DOM tab, search for your variable, then (**similarly to adding a breakpoints to script**) add a `breakpoints`. It will break and scroll to the specific line of code that's going to process the change on the variable.

Check this out -> Firefox [FIREBUG](https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html) OR Google Chrome [DEVELOPER TOOL](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)