# D3.js: listen for changes to an attribute?

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible, in D3.js, to listen for changes to a element attribute?

For example, say I have the following selection:

```
var myDiv = d3.select('#myDiv);
```

Is there any way I can create a listener that will do something whenever any of `myDiv`'s attributes change?

Comment: Not in D3 itself. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860218/javascript-event-listener-for-changes-in-an-object-variable) may be of help though.

Comment: Thanks - if you want to submit that as an answer, I will accept...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript event listener for changes in an object variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860218/javascript-event-listener-for-changes-in-an-object-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in D3 itself. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860218/javascript-event-listener-for-changes-in-an-object-variable) has a few options in Javascript though.