# Add EventLister over Object or property Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, dom-events

I have a Javascript Object with some properties, for example, Clipboard.
here my custom object:

```
MyApp.sessionState
```

and this is the `getProprieties` (returns a `String`)

```
MyApp.sessionState.getProperty("clipboard");
```

This input return for example "this is text".
There is same way to append an `eventListener` "change" on this Object or this string?
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var a = MyApp.sessionState
a.addEventListener("change", function(){console.info("change!")}, false);
```

but returns:

> TypeError: Object # has no method
> 'addEventListener'

Comment: You can't addEventListeners to Objects, it needs to be a DOM element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+listen+for+changes+to+object

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript event listener for changes in an object variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860218/javascript-event-listener-for-changes-in-an-object-variable)

Comment: you can attach events listeners to plain-old JavaScript objects. You would need to manually implement the observer pattern to support that functionality

Comment: Can you show us your implementation of `MyApp.sessionState`, please?