# Order of Operations in Universal Analytics for setting Custom Dimension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My site is moving to Universal Analytics and I'm coming across an issue with the order in which you can push Custom Dimensions to GA.

Previously, you could call _setCustomVar before any other _gaq function and GA would pick it up just fine.

Ie.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, "custom_key", "custom_value", 2]);

// DO OTHER STUFF 

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-545323212-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mysite.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();
```

However, I can't find a way to call this function with Universal analytics before the object is setup:

```
ga('set', 'dimension2', 'CUSTOMDIMENSIONVALUE');

// DO OTHER STUFF

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-434323212-1', 'mysite.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Since `ga()` is a function, how can I call the integration before it exists? Decoding the GA Universal Analytics script, it looks like I could push data into the object, but I've found that nothing takes effect until the `ga('create')` function is called.

I know the simple solution is to move my custom dimension call down to the right order, but thats not an option for me for a number of reasons.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Move the init block and `'create'` call to the top of your page, above where you set your custom code (like in the head tag) and leave the `'send'` call at the bottom of the page, so that your custom code is in between them without you having to actually move the custom code.

Or, leave the main code block you currently have down at the bottom and put a callback function in between the `'create'` and `'send'` and then wrap your custom code in the callback function.

Comment: Lets say I can't move the code anywhere. Would any of the recommendations here work to listen to the ga('create') property to change? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063813/listener-for-property-value-changes-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: @jamis0n You can take the first half of the code block that loads the `analytics.js` file  and put it above your custom code, since it is setup to allow "pushes" before the script is loaded.. but that doesn't get around the fact that the GA script won't recognize "pushes" that happen before the `'create'` "push".  If you reverse engineer `analytics.js`.. obviously there are functions that parse what is passed to `ga()` so it *may* be possible to use the `.prototype` method to override something in there to reorder things, but IMO it's probably not worth trying to do this sort of thing ...

Comment: .. or even worth trying to figure out if it'd even be possible.