# Javascript handling inputs "value"-attribute changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

There's a third-party js-code, which changes my inputs values like this:

```
some_third_party_func = function() { 
    my_input.value = some_val;
};
```

I want to track all the changes of `my_input.value` somehow. Modifying a third-party js is the thing I want to avoid. Probably, events can be useful, but which one? The `oninput` event looks acceptable, except for handling only keyboard input because of some mysterious reasons.

```
my_input.oninput = function() { alert("my_input.oninput"); };
// ^^ alert() runs only when inputting from the keyboard
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sentenzo/14rjst34/) you can try the issue (how it looks for me).

Is there any method to do this (with jQuery, maybe)?

Comment: There is no event raised when the value property of an input is change programmatically. To do what you need you would have to change the source of the plugin to `trigger()` a `change` event.

Comment: my google == your google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063813/listener-for-property-value-changes-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: also wicked: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/

Comment: Sad situation.
Yes.
My search skills are extremely basic.

Comment: polyfill for watch: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch resp. https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583