# Trigger a function when setting an object property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, set

Is there any way to trigger a function when setting the property of an object?

```
function Vector(x,y,z){
this.x= Quaternion(x);
this.y=y;
this.z=z;
}

function Quaternion(x,y,z,w){
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.z=z;
this.w=w;
}
```

Comment: What language is used in this post? If using a specific language, make sure to add the tag.

Comment: Yes, you could do that using a Proxy object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listener for property value changes in a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063813/listener-for-property-value-changes-in-a-javascript-object)